# How to set the profile directory for xulrunner apps using a custom relative path?

Tags: xul, xulrunner, portable-applications

Is there an easy way to create a cross platform portable Xulrunner application?

By "portable" I mean what the guys on http://portableapps.com/ do, but in addition I would like to be able to put on the flash stick whatever platform runtime I need.

For example If I want my application to run on Linux, I put the linux build of Xulrunner and my xulrunner app.
If I want my application to run on Windows I put also the windows build of Xulrunner, etc.

Then the end-user will be able to run the same application depending on the installed platform on the computer that he/she uses.
Everything is ok, suppose I decided how to organize files etc.

The problems comes when the application is run. It finds the default profile directory on the current computer and uses it(NO PORTABLE).
The profile directory should be on the flash-stick.

I tried the following on the command line:

```
#After setting the following in my application.ini
[XRE]
EnableProfileMigrator=1
#and providing the branding information for the profilemanager

~/my/app$ ~/opt/xulrunner/1.9.0.7/xulrunner application.ini -P
```

But this only starts the Profile Manager

After creating a profile i triet to run the app with:

```
~/my/app$ ~/opt/xulrunner/1.9.0.7/xulrunner application.ini \
-profile ../../../opt/xulrunner/j2b59nt8.default
```

Now It seems to work, but still not enough.
So my question should rather be:
*How to set the profile directory for xulrunner apps using a custom relative path?*

*Any Insights?*
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed :)

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Starting_your_Mozilla_application_with_a_specified_profile#Bypassing_the_Profile_Manager
Now I will just need to create a louncher (compiled exe) which finds the needed paths and
runs xulrunner